# Import both R (android.R and <my_package>.R)

Tags: android, android-resources, background-drawable

I'm using custom background in my app. What i'm looking for is how to get `default drawable` from `android.R`. This because if a user select white or dark background, i don't wanna use a custom image, but use for ex: `@android:drawable/screen_background_light` (so, it doesn't take space to save an image).

If i try to `import android.R.*` errors occours (that because im using the other file `R`).

I know how to do it by XML by doing `android:background=@android:drawable/screen_background_light"` , but this is now what i want to do.

Comment: do not `import android.R.*`.

Comment: android.R.drawable.screen_background_light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not import `android.R.*`.

If you want to use the drawable that's in android package use `android.R.drawable.screen_background_light`

Example: say for button set the btn_plus drawable as background

```
   Button b = new Button(ActivityName.this);
   b.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_plus);
```